# Unable to filter out records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

**proxies_meta**

- id - int
- ip_address = varchar
- current_status = int
- updated_at

**proxies**

- id
- ip_address
- hits
- status
- updated_at

*proxies_meta* is like the place where all ip addresses reside while *proxies* gets an entry or gets updated when an ip from *proxies_meta* is used.

Now at given day I have to pick a proxy IP which have not been banned yet that is `status = 0` and `hits` does not cross 10 per day. So far I tried this but not working

```
select pm.ip_address as IP,sum(p.hits) as total_hits
from proxies_meta as pm
LEFT JOIN proxies as p
ON p.ip_address = pm.ip_address
AND pm.`current_status` = 0
AND date(p.updated_at) = '2017-06-23'
GROUP BY IP
having total_hits < 11 OR total_hits is NULL
```

This query works as long as status is `0` or there is no record in `proxies`. If `current_status` and `status` is changed from `0` to `-1` then still it picks because of `LEFT JOIN`

How do I make sure that I don't get the unwanted IP Address and it also checks total hits per day?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need to move condition on current status needs to the `where` clause:

```
select pm.ip_address as IP, sum(p.hits) as total_hits
from proxies_meta pm left join
     proxies p 
     on p.ip_address = pm.ip_address and
        date(p.updated_at) = '2017-06-23'
where pm.current_status = 0
group by pm.ip_address
having total_hits < 11 or total_hits is null;
```

A `left join` keeps all rows in the first table, regardless of whether the `on` clause evaluates to true, false, or `NULL`.  So, conditions on the first table don't filter anything.  For actually filtering, conditions on the first table need to be in the `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I was rather using `AND` clause to filter out.